# Least Squares regression doesn't fit properly

Tags: python, regression

My goal is to fit a decent regression and exclude data that does not fit within a criteria. I need to take data that can correlate well for my project. There is sample data below.

I have an issue with my code for least squares regression. The picture below is one of the plots to display the accepted and unaccepted values in my regression (with an error range). As you can see, the regression doesn't fit it very well, even though it shouldn't be a difficult fit. In some scenarios, only a straight line is drawn.

How can I modify my code to fix this?

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Read the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('Book3.xlsx', header=None)

# Set column names
df.columns = ['col{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(len(df.columns))]

# Extract the unique codes and their corresponding temperature and viscosity values
unique_codes = df['col6'].unique()

# Define a function for the nonlinear regression equation
def viscosity_equation(temp, a, b, c):
    temp = np.array(temp)
    return (a / np.sqrt(temp)) * np.exp((b) / (temp - c))

# Initialize a list to hold the accepted values
accepted_values = []

# Loop through each unique code and perform regression and plot
for code in unique_codes:
    code_data = df[df['col6'] == code]
    if len(code_data) <= 3:
        continue
    temps = code_data['col11']
    viscosities = code_data['col13']

    # Perform the nonlinear regression
    try:
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(viscosity_equation, temps, viscosities, maxfev=2000000)
    except RuntimeError:
        print("Error: Unable to perform regression for code {}".format(code))
        continue

    # Calculate the accepted values within the error range of the regression line
    error_range_percentage = 100  # 10%
    for temp, viscosity in zip(temps, viscosities):
        equation_value = viscosity_equation(temp, *popt)
        if abs((viscosity - equation_value) / viscosity) <= (error_range_percentage / 100):
            accepted_values.append([code, temp, viscosity])

    # Plot the temperature and viscosity values, with the accepted and unaccepted values in different colors
    accepted_temps = []
    accepted_viscosities = []
    unaccepted_temps = []
    unaccepted_viscosities = []
    for temp, viscosity in zip(temps, viscosities):
        equation_value = viscosity_equation(temp, *popt)
        if abs((viscosity - equation_value) / viscosity) <= (error_range_percentage / 100):
            accepted_temps.append(temp)
            accepted_viscosities.append(viscosity)
        else:
            unaccepted_temps.append(temp)
            unaccepted_viscosities.append(viscosity)

    plt.scatter(accepted_temps, accepted_viscosities, color='blue')
    plt.scatter(unaccepted_temps, unaccepted_viscosities, color='red')
    plt.plot(temps, viscosity_equation(temps, *popt), color='black')
    plt.title('Viscosity vs Temperature for Code {}'.format(code))
    plt.xlabel('Temperature')
    plt.ylabel('Viscosity')
    plt.show()

# Create a DataFrame of the accepted values and export to Excel
df_accepted = pd.DataFrame(accepted_values, columns=['cmp1', 'temperature', 'viscosity'])
df_accepted.to_excel('accepted_datasqrtVer.xlsx', index=False)
```

```
| cmp1   | temp    | visc     |
| ------ | ------- | -------- |
| AAaJqR | 293.15  | 0.1113   |
| AAaJqR | 298     | 0.1085   |
| AAaJqR | 298.15  | 0.09     |
| AAaJqR | 303.15  | 0.073    |
| AAaJqR | 308.15  | 0.0602   |
| AAaJqR | 313.15  | 0.0501   |
| AAaJqR | 318.15  | 0.0482   |
| AAaJqR | 323.15  | 0.0407   |
| AAaJqR | 328.15  | 0.0347   |
| AAaJqR | 333.15  | 0.0305   |
| AAaJqR | 338.15  | 0.026    |
| AAaJqR | 343.15  | 0.0227   |
| AAaJqR | 348.15  | 0.0202   |
| AAaJqR | 353.15  | 0.0178   |
| AAbbQy | 298.1   | 0.128    |
| AAbLhO | 303     | 0.07179  |
| AAbLhO | 308     | 0.06003  |
| AAbLhO | 313     | 0.05028  |
| AAbLhO | 318     | 0.04569  |
| AAbLhO | 323     | 0.04074  |
| AAbLhO | 328     | 0.03576  |
| AAbLhO | 333     | 0.03163  |
| AAbRPP | 293.15  | 0.008196 |
| AAbRPP | 298.15  | 0.006926 |
| AAbRPP | 298.15  | 0.00622  |
| AAbRPP | 303.15  | 0.005913 |
| AAbRPP | 308.15  | 0.005069 |
| AAbRPP | 313.15  | 0.004395 |
| AAbvFJ | 293.15  | 0.002451 |
| AAbvFJ | 298.15  | 0.002217 |
| AAbvFJ | 303.15  | 0.00202  |
| AAbvFJ | 308.15  | 0.00185  |
| AAbvFJ | 313.15  | 0.001705 |
| AAbvFJ | 318.15  | 0.00158  |
| AAbvFJ | 323.15  | 0.001472 |
| AAbvFJ | 328.15  | 0.001377 |
| AAbvFJ | 333.15  | 0.001295 |
| AAbvFJ | 338.15  | 0.001223 |
| AAbvFJ | 343.15  | 0.001159 |
| AAcgUH | 303.15  | 0.0594   |
| AAcgUH | 313.15  | 0.0487   |
| AAcgUH | 323.15  | 0.034    |
| AAcgUH | 333.15  | 0.0328   |
| AAcgUH | 343.15  | 0.0278   |
| AAcjwE | 288.15  | 0.432    |
| AAcjwE | 290.65  | 0.359    |
| AAcjwE | 293.15  | 0.302    |
| AAcjwE | 295.65  | 0.256    |
| AAcjwE | 298.15  | 0.215    |
| AAcjwE | 300.65  | 0.183    |
| AAcjwE | 303.15  | 0.158    |
| AAcjwE | 305.15  | 0.141    |
| AAcjwE | 308.15  | 0.118    |
| AAcjwE | 310.15  | 0.1058   |
| AAcjwE | 313.15  | 0.0934   |
| AAcjwE | 315.65  | 0.0812   |
| AAcjwE | 318.15  | 0.0703   |
| AAcjwE | 319.65  | 0.0642   |
| AAcjwE | 323.15  | 0.0551   |
| AAcKcU | 323.15  | 0.34     |
| AAcKcU | 333.15  | 0.173    |
| AAcKcU | 343.15  | 0.1      |
| AAcKcU | 353.15  | 0.065    |
| AAcKcU | 353.15  | 0.0612   |
| AAcKcU | 363.15  | 0.0391   |
| AAcKcU | 373.1   | 0.027    |
| AAcKcU | 393.1   | 0.013    |
| AAdDEf | 293.15  | 0.808    |
| AAdDEf | 293.15  | 0.471    |
| AAdDEf | 298.15  | 0.533    |
| AAdDEf | 298.15  | 0.95     |
| AAdDEf | 303.15  | 0.37     |
| AAdDEf | 303.15  | 0.242    |
| AAdDEf | 308.15  | 0.52     |
| AAdDEf | 313.15  | 0.135    |
| AAdDEf | 318.15  | 0.269    |
| AAdDEf | 323.15  | 0.1062   |
| AAdDEf | 323.15  | 0.082    |
| AAdDEf | 328.15  | 0.152    |
| AAdDEf | 333.15  | 0.053    |
| AAdDEf | 338.15  | 0.092    |
| AAdDEf | 343.15  | 0.04109  |
| AAdDEf | 343.15  | 0.0359   |
| AAdDEf | 348.15  | 0.058    |
| AAdDtp | 298.1   | 1.324    |
| AAdDtp | 298.2   | 1.2      |
| AAdDtp | 298.2   | 0.254    |
| AAdDtp | 303.2   | 0.181    |
| AAdDtp | 308.2   | 0.133    |
| AAdDtp | 313.2   | 0.1      |
| AAdDtp | 318.2   | 0.077    |
| AAdDtp | 323.2   | 0.06     |
| AAdDtp | 328.2   | 0.0481   |
| AAdDtp | 333.2   | 0.0381   |
| AAdDtp | 338.2   | 0.031    |
| AAdDtp | 343.2   | 0.025    |
| AAdDtp | 348.2   | 0.0213   |
| AAdwKx | 303.15  | 0.512    |
| AAdwKx | 313.15  | 0.278    |
| AAdwKx | 323.15  | 0.164    |
| AAdwKx | 333.15  | 0.1041   |
| AAdwKx | 343.15  | 0.0704   |
| AAdXKY | 299.25  | 0.002444 |
| AAdXKY | 308.15  | 0.002039 |
| AAdXKY | 323.65  | 0.001532 |
| AAdXKY | 340.25  | 0.001211 |
| AAdXKY | 352.85  | 0.001009 |
| AAeamZ | 298.15  | 0.255    |
| AAeamZ | 298.15  | 0.82     |
| AAeamZ | 307     | 0.79     |
| AAeamZ | 311.7   | 0.53     |
| AAeamZ | 319.9   | 0.28     |
| AAeamZ | 330     | 0.15     |
| AAeamZ | 337.1   | 0.1      |
| AAeamZ | 347.3   | 0.061    |
| AAeamZ | 361.1   | 0.035    |
| AAeamZ | 373.2   | 0.024    |
| AAeBoH | 283.15  | 0.0079   |
| AAeBoH | 288.15  | 0.0067   |
| AAeBoH | 293.15  | 0.0053   |
| AAeBoH | 298.15  | 0.005    |
| AAeBoH | 303.15  | 0.0043   |
| AAeBoH | 308.15  | 0.0038   |
| AAeBoH | 313.15  | 0.0032   |
| AAeBoH | 318.15  | 0.0031   |
| AAeBoH | 323.15  | 0.0027   |
| AAeBoH | 328.15  | 0.0025   |
| AAeBoH | 333.15  | 0.0022   |
| AAeBoH | 338.15  | 0.0021   |
| AAeBoH | 343.15  | 0.00191  |
| AAeBoH | 348.15  | 0.00176  |
| AAeBoH | 353.15  | 0.00155  |
| AAeBoH | 358.15  | 0.00152  |
| AAeBoH | 363.15  | 0.00141  |
| AAeBWF | 293.15  | 0.0906   |
| AAeBWF | 295.16  | 0.0893   |
| AAeBWF | 298.15  | 0.087    |
| AAeBWF | 303.09  | 0.0849   |
| AAeBWF | 308.13  | 0.0815   |
| AAeBWF | 313.17  | 0.0783   |
| AAeBWF | 318.16  | 0.0754   |
| AAeBWF | 323.11  | 0.0729   |
| AAeBWF | 328.14  | 0.0708   |
| AAeBWF | 330.09  | 0.0703   |
| AAeBWF | 333.16  | 0.0692   |
| AAeBWF | 335.05  | 0.0685   |
| AAeBWF | 338.14  | 0.0673   |
| AAefWH | 293.15  | 0.002933 |
| AAefWH | 298.15  | 0.002622 |
| AAefWH | 303.15  | 0.002364 |
| AAefWH | 308.15  | 0.002144 |
| AAefWH | 313.15  | 0.001959 |
| AAefWH | 318.15  | 0.001799 |
| AAefWH | 323.15  | 0.00166  |
| AAefWH | 328.15  | 0.00154  |
| AAefWH | 333.15  | 0.001435 |
| AAefWH | 338.15  | 0.001344 |
| AAefWH | 343.15  | 0.001264 |
| AAeLiY | 298.15  | 0.0051   |
| AAeLiY | 298.15  | 0.0051   |
| AAeLiY | 298.15  | 0.0051   |
| AAeLiY | 303.15  | 0.00448  |
| AAeLiY | 303.15  | 0.00448  |
| AAeLiY | 308.15  | 0.00394  |
| AAeLiY | 308.15  | 0.00394  |
| AAeLiY | 313.15  | 0.00316  |
| AAeLiY | 313.15  | 0.00316  |
| AAeLOP | 298.15  | 0.00764  |
| AAeLOP | 298.15  | 0.00764  |
| AAeLOP | 303.15  | 0.00646  |
| AAeLOP | 303.15  | 0.00646  |
| AAeLOP | 308.15  | 0.00561  |
| AAeLOP | 308.15  | 0.00561  |
| AAeLOP | 313.15  | 0.00507  |
| AAeLOP | 313.15  | 0.00507  |
| AAfAom | 298     | 0.0153   |
| AAfAom | 298.15  | 0.02414  |
| AAfAom | 298.15  | 0.0241   |
| AAfAom | 298.15  | 0.02412  |
| AAfAom | 298.2   | 0.0142   |
| AAfAom | 303.15  | 0.01964  |
| AAfAom | 308     | 0.0115   |
| AAfAom | 308.15  | 0.01613  |
| AAfAom | 308.2   | 0.0101   |
| AAfAom | 318     | 0.0089   |
| AAfAom | 318.2   | 0.0076   |
| AAfAom | 328     | 0.0069   |
| AAfAom | 328.2   | 0.0059   |
| AAfAom | 338     | 0.0055   |
| AAfAom | 338.2   | 0.0051   |
| AAfTUy | 293     | 0.0155   |
| AAfUHx | 288.15  | 0.61     |
| AAfUHx | 290.15  | 0.516    |
| AAfUHx | 293.1   | 0.323    |
| AAfUHx | 293.15  | 0.434    |
| AAfUHx | 295.65  | 0.352    |
| AAfUHx | 298.15  | 0.299    |
| AAfUHx | 300.65  | 0.257    |
| AAfUHx | 303.1   | 0.1807   |
| AAfUHx | 303.15  | 0.219    |
| AAfUHx | 305.45  | 0.186    |
| AAfUHx | 308.15  | 0.163    |
| AAfUHx | 310.65  | 0.141    |
| AAfUHx | 312.65  | 0.1271   |
| AAfUHx | 313.1   | 0.11     |
| AAfUHx | 315.15  | 0.1078   |
| AAfUHx | 318.15  | 0.0933   |
| AAfUHx | 320.15  | 0.0796   |
| AAfUHx | 323.1   | 0.071    |
| AAfUHx | 323.15  | 0.0715   |
| AAfUHx | 333.1   | 0.0459   |
| AAfUHx | 343.1   | 0.0328   |
| AAfUHx | 353.1   | 0.0229   |
| AAfUHx | 363.1   | 0.0181   |
| AAfUHx | 373.1   | 0.0143   |
| AAfUpd | 288.15  | 0.301    |
| AAfUpd | 293.15  | 0.221    |
| AAfUpd | 298.15  | 0.163    |
| AAfUpd | 303.15  | 0.1247   |
| AAfUpd | 308.15  | 0.0983   |
| AAfUpd | 313.15  | 0.0758   |
| AAfUpd | 318.15  | 0.0601   |
| AAfUpd | 323.15  | 0.048    |
| AAgcxF | 278.15  | 0.05457  |
| AAgcxF | 283     | 0.039    |
| AAgcxF | 283.15  | 0.04351  |
| AAgcxF | 283.15  | 0.03841  |
| AAgcxF | 288.1   | 0.0319   |
| AAgcxF | 288.15  | 0.03424  |
| AAgcxF | 288.15  | 0.03536  |
| AAgcxF | 288.15  | 0.03458  |
| AAgcxF | 293.1   | 0.0263   |
| AAgcxF | 293.15  | 0.0279   |
| AAgcxF | 293.15  | 0.02921  |
| AAgcxF | 293.15  | 0.02827  |
| AAgcxF | 293.15  | 0.02973  |
| AAgcxF | 293.15  | 0.02631  |
| AAgcxF | 293.15  | 0.02676  |
| AAgcxF | 293.15  | 0.02856  |
| AAgcxF | 298     | 0.0222   |
| AAgcxF | 298.15  | 0.02268  |
| AAgcxF | 298.15  | 0.0245   |
| AAgcxF | 298.15  | 0.0236   |
| AAgcxF | 298.15  | 0.02379  |
| AAgcxF | 298.15  | 0.02504  |
| AAgcxF | 298.15  | 0.024    |
| AAgcxF | 298.15  | 0.02311  |
| AAgcxF | 298.15  | 0.02393  |
| AAgcxF | 303     | 0.019    |
| AAgcxF | 303.15  | 0.01909  |
| AAgcxF | 303.15  | 0.02079  |
| AAgcxF | 303.15  | 0.02025  |
| AAgcxF | 303.15  | 0.02133  |
| AAgcxF | 303.15  | 0.01903  |
| AAgcxF | 303.15  | 0.0176   |
| AAgcxF | 303.15  | 0.02012  |
| AAgcxF | 303.15  | 0.02032  |
| AAgcxF | 308     | 0.0164   |
| AAgcxF | 308.15  | 0.01639  |
| AAgcxF | 308.15  | 0.01786  |
| AAgcxF | 308.15  | 0.01841  |
| AAgcxF | 308.15  | 0.0138   |
| AAgcxF | 308.15  | 0.0175   |
| AAgcxF | 308.15  | 0.01746  |
| AAgcxF | 313     | 0.0142   |
| AAgcxF | 313.15  | 0.01418  |
| AAgcxF | 313.15  | 0.01549  |
| AAgcxF | 313.15  | 0.01513  |
| AAgcxF | 313.15  | 0.01602  |
| AAgcxF | 313.15  | 0.0143   |
| AAgcxF | 313.15  | 0.0112   |
| AAgcxF | 313.15  | 0.01532  |
| AAgcxF | 313.15  | 0.01514  |
| AAgcxF | 318.1   | 0.0125   |
| AAgcxF | 318.15  | 0.01243  |
| AAgcxF | 318.15  | 0.01356  |
| AAgcxF | 318.15  | 0.01408  |
| AAgcxF | 318.15  | 0.0097   |
| AAgcxF | 318.15  | 0.01345  |
| AAgcxF | 318.15  | 0.01325  |
| AAgcxF | 323     | 0.0112   |
| AAgcxF | 323.15  | 0.01197  |
| AAgcxF | 323.15  | 0.01173  |
| AAgcxF | 323.15  | 0.01252  |
| AAgcxF | 323.15  | 0.0111   |
| AAgcxF | 323.15  | 0.0086   |
| AAgcxF | 323.15  | 0.01178  |
| AAgcxF | 323.15  | 0.0117   |
| AAgcxF | 328     | 0.01     |
| AAgcxF | 328.15  | 0.01064  |
| AAgcxF | 328.15  | 0.01116  |
| AAgcxF | 328.15  | 0.01037  |
| AAgcxF | 328.15  | 0.0104   |
| AAgcxF | 333.1   | 0.009    |
| AAgcxF | 333.15  | 0.00953  |
| AAgcxF | 333.15  | 0.00936  |
| AAgcxF | 333.15  | 0.01005  |
| AAgcxF | 333.15  | 0.0071   |
| AAgcxF | 333.15  | 0.00921  |
| AAgcxF | 333.15  | 0.0093   |
| AAgcxF | 338     | 0.008    |
| AAgcxF | 338.15  | 0.008582 |
| AAgcxF | 338.15  | 0.0091   |
| AAgcxF | 338.18  | 0.0081   |
| AAgcxF | 343     | 0.0073   |
| AAgcxF | 343.15  | 0.007773 |
| AAgcxF | 343.15  | 0.00765  |
| AAgcxF | 343.15  | 0.008318 |
| AAgcxF | 343.15  | 0.007236 |
| AAgcxF | 347.9   | 0.0066   |
| AAgcxF | 348.15  | 0.007076 |
| AAgcxF | 353     | 0.0058   |
| AAgcxF | 353.15  | 0.006472 |
| AAgcxF | 353.15  | 0.00638  |
| AAgcxF | 358.15  | 0.005945 |
| AAgcxF | 363.15  | 0.005485 |
| AAgHkg | 293.15  | 0.09032  |
| AAgHkg | 303.15  | 0.05283  |
| AAgHkg | 313.15  | 0.03366  |
| AAgHkg | 323.15  | 0.02265  |
| AAgHkg | 333.15  | 0.01499  |
| AAgHkg | 343.15  | 0.010466 |
| AAgHkg | 353.15  | 0.007478 |
| AAgHkg | 363.15  | 0.005425 |
| AAgmgm | 273     | 1.0245   |
| AAgmgm | 278.1   | 0.599    |
| AAgmgm | 278.15  | 0.724    |
| AAgmgm | 278.15  | 0.7      |
| AAgmgm | 278.15  | 0.69     |
| AAgmgm | 282.5   | 0.354    |
| AAgmgm | 283     | 0.377    |
| AAgmgm | 283.15  | 0.451    |
| AAgmgm | 283.15  | 0.389    |
| AAgmgm | 288.1   | 0.2485   |
| AAgmgm | 288.15  | 0.296    |
| AAgmgm | 288.15  | 0.258    |
| AAgmgm | 288.15  | 0.353    |
| AAgmgm | 288.15  | 0.288    |
| AAgmgm | 288.15  | 0.29     |
| AAgmgm | 288.15  | 0.2838   |
| AAgmgm | 288.15  | 0.284    |
| AAgmgm | 288.15  | 0.228    |
| AAgmgm | 292.4   | 0.156    |
| AAgmgm | 293     | 0.1841   |
| AAgmgm | 293.1   | 0.1686   |
| AAgmgm | 293.15  | 0.202    |
| AAgmgm | 293.15  | 0.1791   |
| AAgmgm | 293.15  | 0.238    |
| AAgmgm | 293.15  | 0.197    |
| AAgmgm | 293.15  | 0.203    |
| AAgmgm | 293.15  | 0.1111   |
| AAgmgm | 296.15  | 0.155    |
| AAgmgm | 298     | 0.1215   |
| AAgmgm | 298.1   | 0.16     |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.162    |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.1436   |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.1285   |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.1329   |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.167    |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.1284   |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.14     |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.141    |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.1263   |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.1339   |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.139    |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.139    |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.124    |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.092    |
| AAgmgm | 298.15  | 0.1384   |
| AAgmgm | 302.1   | 0.085    |
| AAgmgm | 303     | 0.0991   |
| AAgmgm | 303.1   | 0.0875   |
| AAgmgm | 303.15  | 0.1053   |
| AAgmgm | 303.15  | 0.0952   |
| AAgmgm | 303.15  | 0.098    |
| AAgmgm | 303.15  | 0.1209   |
| AAgmgm | 303.15  | 0.0951   |
| AAgmgm | 303.15  | 0.1024   |
| AAgmgm | 303.15  | 0.0936   |
| AAgmgm | 303.15  | 0.1048   |
| AAgmgm | 303.15  | 0.05912  |
| AAgmgm | 308     | 0.0659   |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.0793   |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.0724   |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.0743   |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.0901   |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.0724   |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.0783   |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.0783   |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.0713   |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.0773   |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.0773   |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.069    |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.04379  |
| AAgmgm | 308.15  | 0.0761   |
| AAgmgm | 312.5   | 0.051    |
| AAgmgm | 313.1   | 0.0519   |
| AAgmgm | 313.15  | 0.06133  |
| AAgmgm | 313.15  | 0.0564   |
| AAgmgm | 313.15  | 0.0577   |
| AAgmgm | 313.15  | 0.0688   |
| AAgmgm | 313.15  | 0.0564   |
| AAgmgm | 313.15  | 0.0604   |
| AAgmgm | 313.15  | 0.0555   |
| AAgmgm | 313.15  | 0.0611   |
| AAgmgm | 313.15  | 0.03246  |
| AAgmgm | 318     | 0.0415   |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.04841  |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.0448   |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.0458   |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.0537   |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.0448   |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.0477   |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.0477   |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.0442   |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.04737  |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.0474   |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.0414   |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.02795  |
| AAgmgm | 318.15  | 0.0459   |
| AAgmgm | 322.6   | 0.032    |
| AAgmgm | 323     | 0.0383   |
| AAgmgm | 323.1   | 0.0337   |
| AAgmgm | 323.15  | 0.03895  |
| AAgmgm | 323.15  | 0.0362   |
| AAgmgm | 323.15  | 0.0369   |
| AAgmgm | 323.15  | 0.0427   |
| AAgmgm | 323.15  | 0.03627  |
| AAgmgm | 323.15  | 0.039    |
| AAgmgm | 323.15  | 0.0357   |
| AAgmgm | 323.15  | 0.0389   |
| AAgmgm | 323.15  | 0.02098  |
| AAgmgm | 328.1   | 0.0278   |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.03187  |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.0298   |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.0303   |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.0346   |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.02981  |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.0312   |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.0313   |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.03129  |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.0313   |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.0265   |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.01699  |
| AAgmgm | 328.15  | 0.0301   |
| AAgmgm | 332.2   | 0.023    |
| AAgmgm | 333     | 0.0268   |
| AAgmgm | 333     | 0.0236   |
| AAgmgm | 333.15  | 0.02647  |
| AAgmgm | 333.15  | 0.0248   |
| AAgmgm | 333.15  | 0.0252   |
| AAgmgm | 333.15  | 0.0285   |
| AAgmgm | 333.15  | 0.02486  |
| AAgmgm | 333.15  | 0.0267   |
| AAgmgm | 333.15  | 0.02656  |
| AAgmgm | 333.15  | 0.01411  |
| AAgmgm | 338     | 0.02     |
| AAgmgm | 338.15  | 0.02227  |
| AAgmgm | 338.15  | 0.02095  |
| AAgmgm | 338.15  | 0.02124  |
| AAgmgm | 338.15  | 0.0237   |
| AAgmgm | 338.15  | 0.0218   |
| AAgmgm | 338.15  | 0.0218   |
| AAgmgm | 338.15  | 0.02185  |
| AAgmgm | 338.15  | 0.02185  |
| AAgmgm | 338.15  | 0.0183   |
| AAgmgm | 338.15  | 0.01201  |
| AAgmgm | 338.15  | 0.0208   |
| AAgmgm | 341.3   | 0.016    |
| AAgmgm | 343     | 0.0194   |
| AAgmgm | 343     | 0.0172   |
| AAgmgm | 343.15  | 0.01896  |
| AAgmgm | 343.15  | 0.01788  |
| AAgmgm | 343.15  | 0.0181   |
| AAgmgm | 343.15  | 0.02     |
| AAgmgm | 343.15  | 0.0188   |
| AAgmgm | 343.15  | 0.01901  |
| AAgmgm | 343.15  | 0.0099   |
| AAgmgm | 348.15  | 0.01631  |
| AAgmgm | 348.15  | 0.01601  |
| AAgmgm | 348.15  | 0.016    |
| AAgmgm | 348.15  | 0.01601  |
| AAgmgm | 348.15  | 0.0133   |
| AAgmgm | 348.15  | 0.008458 |
| AAgmgm | 348.15  | 0.01428  |
| AAgmgm | 348.4   | 0.0153   |
| AAgmgm | 352.1   | 0.013    |
| AAgmgm | 353     | 0.0151   |
| AAgmgm | 353     | 0.0136   |
| AAgmgm | 353.15  | 0.017    |
| AAgmgm | 353.15  | 0.01416  |
| AAgmgm | 353.15  | 0.01407  |
| AAgmgm | 353.15  | 0.01424  |
| AAgmgm | 353.15  | 0.00745  |
| AAgmgm | 358.15  | 0.01241  |
| AAgmgm | 358.15  | 0.01219  |
| AAgmgm | 358.15  | 0.0101   |
| AAgmgm | 358.15  | 0.00687  |
| AAgmgm | 358.15  | 0.01153  |
| AAgmgm | 358.2   | 0.0122   |
| AAgmgm | 362.3   | 0.01     |
| AAgmgm | 363     | 0.0118   |
| AAgmgm | 363.1   | 0.011    |
| AAgmgm | 363.15  | 0.01095  |
| AAgmgm | 363.15  | 0.006113 |
| AAgmgm | 368     | 0.0102   |
| AAgmgm | 368.15  | 0.00956  |
| AAgmgm | 368.15  | 0.005543 |
| AAgmgm | 371.7   | 0.0091   |
| AAgmgm | 373.1   | 0.009    |
| AAgmgm | 373.15  | 0.004876 |
| AAgmgm | 373.4   | 0.0095   |
| AAgmgm | 378.15  | 0.00771  |
| AAgmgm | 388.15  | 0.00636  |
| AAgmgm | 393.1   | 0.005    |
| AAgmgm | 398.15  | 0.00536  |
| AAgmgm | 408.15  | 0.00459  |
| AAgwiX | 293     | 0.0909   |
| AAgwiX | 303     | 0.0593   |
| AAgwiX | 313     | 0.0393   |
| AAgwiX | 323     | 0.0277   |
| AAgwiX | 333     | 0.0203   |
| AAgwiX | 343     | 0.0153   |
| AAgwiX | 353     | 0.0116   |
| AAgwiX | 363     | 0.0091   |
| AAgwJR | 293     | 0.1732   |
| AAgwJR | 303     | 0.0966   |
| AAgwJR | 313     | 0.0593   |
| AAgwJR | 323     | 0.0397   |
| AAgwJR | 333     | 0.027    |
| AAgwJR | 343     | 0.0203   |
| AAgwJR | 353     | 0.0148   |
| AAgwJR | 363     | 0.0115   |
| AAgwVg | 298.15  | 0.0341   |
| AAgwVg | 298.15  | 0.0341   |
| AAhalr | 298.15  | 0.01892  |
| AAhalr | 303.15  | 0.01644  |
| AAhalr | 308.15  | 0.01431  |
| AAhalr | 313.15  | 0.01248  |
| AAhalr | 318.15  | 0.01098  |
| AAhalr | 323.15  | 0.00948  |
| AAhalr | 328.15  | 0.00852  |
| AAhalr | 333.15  | 0.00769  |
| AAhalr | 338.15  | 0.00691  |
| AAhAvC | 413.1   | 0.0218   |
| AAhAvC | 418.1   | 0.019    |
| AAhAvC | 423.1   | 0.01671  |
| AAhAvC | 428.1   | 0.01477  |
| AAhAvC | 433.1   | 0.01314  |
| AAhAvC | 438.1   | 0.01175  |
| AAhAvC | 443.1   | 0.01056  |
| AAhAvC | 448.1   | 0.00955  |
| AAhAvC | 453.1   | 0.00867  |
| AAhAvC | 458.1   | 0.00883  |
| AAhevu | 283.15  | 140      |
| AAhevu | 293.15  | 41       |
| AAhevu | 303.15  | 11       |
| AAhevu | 313.15  | 3.8      |
| AAhevu | 323.15  | 1.5      |
| AAhevu | 333.15  | 0.7      |
| AAhevu | 343     | 0.1987   |
| AAhevu | 343.15  | 0.33     |
| AAhevu | 343.15  | 0.257    |
| AAhevu | 348.15  | 0.217    |
| AAhevu | 348.15  | 0.189    |
| AAhevu | 353     | 0.1197   |
| AAhevu | 353.15  | 0.142    |
| AAhevu | 353.15  | 0.1621   |
| AAhevu | 353.15  | 0.182    |
| AAhevu | 353.15  | 0.143    |
| AAhevu | 358.15  | 0.1233   |
| AAhevu | 358.15  | 0.11     |
| AAhevu | 363.1   | 0.0732   |
| AAhevu | 363.15  | 0.0956   |
| AAhevu | 363.15  | 0.105    |
| AAhevu | 363.15  | 0.0857   |
| AAhevu | 368.15  | 0.0754   |
| AAhevu | 373.1   | 0.068    |
| AAhevu | 373.1   | 0.0482   |
| AAhevu | 373.15  | 0.0603   |
| AAhevu | 382.9   | 0.0313   |
| AAhevu | 393     | 0.0239   |
| AAhevu | 393.1   | 0.031    |
| AAhkDu | 298.15  | 0.018    |
| AAhNhy | 305     | 0.0277   |
| AAhNhy | 309     | 0.0247   |
| AAhNhy | 313     | 0.0222   |
| AAhNhy | 316.9   | 0.0202   |
| AAhNhy | 322.1   | 0.0177   |
| AAhNhy | 328     | 0.0154   |
| AAhNhy | 332.9   | 0.0137   |
| AAhNhy | 338.5   | 0.0123   |
| AAhNhy | 344     | 0.0111   |
| AAhNhy | 349     | 0.01     |
| AAhNhy | 354     | 0.0092   |
| AAhPAl | 313.15  | 0.0338   |
| AAhPAl | 323.15  | 0.0262   |
| AAhPAl | 333.15  | 0.0187   |
| AAhPAl | 343.15  | 0.0147   |
| AAhPAl | 353.15  | 0.0113   |
| AAhPAl | 363.15  | 0.00887  |
| AAhQPf | 293.15  | 0.003136 |
| AAhQPf | 298.15  | 0.002801 |
| AAhQPf | 303.15  | 0.002518 |
| AAhQPf | 308.15  | 0.00228  |
| AAhQPf | 313.15  | 0.002075 |
| AAhQPf | 318.15  | 0.0019   |
| AAhQPf | 323.15  | 0.00175  |
| AAhQPf | 328.15  | 0.001619 |
| AAhQPf | 333.15  | 0.001506 |
| AAhQPf | 338.15  | 0.001407 |
| AAhQPf | 343.15  | 0.00132  |
| AAhQZr | 298.15  | 0.24     |
| AAhQZr | 303.15  | 0.184    |
| AAhQZr | 308.15  | 0.145    |
| AAhQZr | 313.15  | 0.117    |
| AAhQZr | 318.15  | 0.0934   |
| AAhQZr | 323.15  | 0.074    |
| AAhQZr | 328.15  | 0.06     |
| AAhQZr | 333.15  | 0.0492   |
| AAhQZr | 338.15  | 0.0394   |
| AAhQZr | 343.15  | 0.0324   |
| AAhQZr | 348.15  | 0.026    |
| AAiEls | 293.01  | 5.4      |
| AAiEls | 293.15  | 4.6      |
| AAiEls | 298.11  | 3.4      |
| AAiEls | 298.15  | 2.919    |
| AAiEls | 303.14  | 2.2      |
| AAiEls | 303.15  | 1.91     |
| AAiEls | 308.08  | 1.511    |
| AAiEls | 308.15  | 1.285    |
| AAiEls | 313.05  | 1.021    |
| AAiEls | 313.15  | 0.89     |
| AAiEls | 318.08  | 0.72     |
| AAiEls | 318.15  | 0.63     |
| AAiEls | 323.1   | 0.51     |
| AAiEls | 323.15  | 0.455    |
| AAiEls | 328.15  | 0.337    |
| AAiEls | 328.59  | 0.372    |
| AAiEls | 332.96  | 0.283    |
| AAiEls | 333.15  | 0.254    |
| AAiEls | 338.1   | 0.217    |
| AAiEls | 338.15  | 0.195    |
| AAiEls | 343     | 0.166    |
| AAiEls | 343.15  | 0.152    |
| AAiEls | 348     | 0.131    |
| AAiEls | 352.89  | 0.104    |
| AAiEls | 358.03  | 0.0834   |
| AAiEls | 363.22  | 0.0653   |
| AAiEls | 368.66  | 0.0533   |
```

Comment: Maybe the model function is not suitable for your data? Can you show how you manually set the model parameters that make the function fit reasonably?

Comment: I am using an equation called Vogel-Fulcher-Tammann (VFT). I just took an initial guess of [1, 1, 1] by default. I have changed it around as [1, -1, -1] but little changed. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I meant: which values for the parameters did you expect the code to output but it didn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered doing a linear transformation using the formulaic relationship that you propose, or are you required/inclined to do non-linear regression?  I took a stab at a transform + linear, which is cleaner.  Maybe useful as a basis for comparison.

It is "pretty solid" when I tested on most of your liquid types in the data.  You could argue against the fit a bit because the residuals are clearly non-linear, but their distribution is quite tight and the range of temperatures is enormous, so a more localized model might be slightly more convincing.

Anyhow...

If you want to fit to the underlying formula in your code that

```
V ~ a * exp(b/(t - c))    # from Wikipedia on V-F-T formula
```

This formulation suggests a double transform on V & t might work to arrive at:

```
V' ~  + t'
```

Where

```
V' = ln(viscosity)
t' = 1/temp
```

So, tried that out w/ some success below...  Some fits better than others.

#### Code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict
from math import log
from scipy.stats import linregress


data = \
...  # just a cut & paste of your data above as a big string... omitted for clarity here


temps = defaultdict(list)
viscs = defaultdict(list)
observations = {}
for line in data.split('\n'):
    tokens = line.strip().split('|')
    fluid = tokens[1].replace(' ','')
    temp = float(tokens[2])
    visc = float(tokens[3])

    temps[fluid].append(temp)
    viscs[fluid].append(visc)

# let's look at one fluid that has reasonable data count...

fluid = 'AAgmgm'
plt.scatter(temps[fluid], viscs[fluid])
plt.title(f'Original Data: {fluid}')
plt.show()


v_prime = [log(v) for v in viscs[fluid]]
t_prime = [1/t for t in temps[fluid]]

plt.scatter(t_prime, v_prime)

res = linregress(t_prime, v_prime)

print(res)

def predict(x):
    return res.intercept + res.slope*x

plt_range = [min(t_prime), max(t_prime)]
pred_vals = [predict(x) for x in plt_range]
plt.plot(plt_range, pred_vals, color='r')
plt.title(f'linear transformation.  P-value: {res.pvalue : 0.3e}')
plt.show()

predicted = [predict(t) for t in t_prime]
residuals = [p - v_p for (p, v_p) in zip(predicted, v_prime)]

plt.scatter(t_prime, residuals)
plt.title('Residuals')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also explored a bit over synthetic data to fit classic [OLS LR](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares) and [NNLS LR](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#non-negative-least-squares) using `sklearn` as well as [OLS_sm](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) from `sm` packages over generated data like what OP offered, but I got this [output](https://i.imgur.com/o6tKMej.jpg); nevertheless, your output is promising. Wasn't it possible to use these packages for this matter?

Comment: @Mario  What data did you use to get that and did you transform it?  The residuals look quite good from the limited info in the pic.  Obviously some transform must take place to use linear regression on the data provided as the relationship is clearly non-linear.

Comment: I used generated data suggested [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_nnls.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-nnls-py) but with 2 columns `n_samples, n_features = 200, 2`. I couldn't figure it out like you to collect data. If there was a chance to have data as dataframe I could experiment better. I didn't use transform. Would you elaborate on why we need to transform? Is it because the original data is non-linear? Then apply OLS\NNLS LR over the transformed data based on the proposed formula you addressed. Right? I just want to understand and learn.

Comment: @Mario Well, it is a little beyond the scope of comments to cover many details…. There are many online tutorials available.  The data provided here is clearly “curved” so the relationship between Temp & Viscosity is obviously non-linear.  Drawing a straight line across a curved line is a cruddy estimate.  So, transforms are sometimes used to try to “straighten” things out.  And there are many types of curves, 1/x, x^2, x^3, ln(x), etc etc.  The formula provided was a suggestion of an approach

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, and that can explain why you use it. Probably once I transformed feature `temp` by `1/t` and `log(v)` for feature `viscs`, I could apply sklearn-based OLS & NNLS linear regressions correctly